# JBPM6 integrating with jboss eap 6.1

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss, jax-rs, jbpm

i have i problem when i invoke jbpm6 specified 6.0.3 with api rest, when a call with postman to execute its fails. My application its a web project using eap 6.1. I don't know if this module jbpm6 have conflicts with eap 6.1 ?, but the documentation to consume this is like the code below. Can you have any idea of what should be ?

my portion of code when fails:

```
    RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory remoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory = null;
        try {
            remoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory =
                    RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactory.newBuilder()
                            .addDeploymentId(deploymentId)
                            .addUrl(baseUrl)
                            .addUserName(user)
                            .addPassword(password)
                            .addTimeout(10000).build();
        } catch (InsufficientInfoToBuildException e) {
            System.err.println("insuficiente info: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

My logger:

```
22:20:05,771 ERROR [org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.[jboss.web].[default-host].[/jbpmRest].[jbpm603.rest.JaxRsActivator]] (http-localhost/127.0.0.1:8080-1) JBWEB000236: Servlet.service() for servlet jbpm603.rest.JaxRsActivator threw exception: org.jboss.resteasy.spi.UnhandledException: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/kie/services/client/api/command/RemoteConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, org/jboss/resteasy/client/core/executors/ApacheHttpClient4Executor, have different Class objects for the type xecutors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)V used in the signature
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleApplicationException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:365) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:233) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.handleInvokerException(SynchronousDispatcher.java:209) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:557) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:524) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.invoke(SynchronousDispatcher.java:126) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.ServletContainerDispatcher.service(ServletContainerDispatcher.java:208) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:55) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.plugins.server.servlet.HttpServletDispatcher.service(HttpServletDispatcher.java:50) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:847) [jboss-servlet-api_3.0_spec-1.0.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:1.0.2.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:295) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:214) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:230) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:149) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.as.web.security.SecurityContextAssociationValve.invoke(SecurityContextAssociationValve.java:169) [jboss-as-web-7.2.0.Final-redhat-8.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-8]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:145) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:97) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:102) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:336) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.process(Http11Processor.java:856) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol$Http11ConnectionHandler.process(Http11Protocol.java:653) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$Worker.run(JIoEndpoint.java:920) [jbossweb-7.2.0.Final-redhat-1.jar:7.2.0.Final-redhat-1]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
Caused by: java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "org.jboss.resteasy.client.core.executors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)V" the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) of the current class, org/kie/services/client/api/command/RemoteConfiguration, and the class loader (instance of org/jboss/modules/ModuleClassLoader) for resolved class, org/jboss/resteasy/client/core/executors/ApacheHttpClient4Executor, have different Class objects for the type xecutors.ApacheHttpClient4Executor.<init>(Lorg/apache/http/client/HttpClient;Lorg/apache/http/protocol/HttpContext;)V used in the signature
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.RemoteConfiguration.createAuthenticatingRequestFactory(RemoteConfiguration.java:189) [kie-services-client-6.0.3-redhat-6.jar:6.0.3-redhat-6]
    at org.kie.services.client.api.command.RemoteConfiguration.createRequestFactory(RemoteConfiguration.java:137) [kie-services-client-6.0.3-redhat-6.jar:6.0.3-redhat-6]
    at org.kie.services.client.api.RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactoryBuilderImpl.build(RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactoryBuilderImpl.java:93) [kie-services-client-6.0.3-redhat-6.jar:6.0.3-redhat-6]
    at org.kie.services.client.api.RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactoryBuilderImpl.build(RemoteRestRuntimeEngineFactoryBuilderImpl.java:12) [kie-services-client-6.0.3-redhat-6.jar:6.0.3-redhat-6]
    at jbpm603.ProcessISL.javaRemoteApiRestExample(ProcessISL.java:52) [classes:]
    at jbpm603.rest.ServiceJbpmRest.startProcess(ServiceJbpmRest.java:38) [classes:]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606) [rt.jar:1.7.0_80]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.MethodInjectorImpl.invoke(MethodInjectorImpl.java:167) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invokeOnTarget(ResourceMethod.java:269) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:227) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.ResourceMethod.invoke(ResourceMethod.java:216) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    at org.jboss.resteasy.core.SynchronousDispatcher.getResponse(SynchronousDispatcher.java:542) [resteasy-jaxrs-2.3.6.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.3.6.Final-redhat-1]
    ... 19 more
```